# find and copy so files while removing all but major version number

Tags: linux, shell

Trying to use "find" to copy a bunch of shared objects. Almost there, but would like to remove all version numbers except the major version.
example would be somesharedobject.so.30.0.4 copied to somesharedobject.so.30

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.so.*' -exec cp '{}' test/'{}' \;`

I'm guessing I'm going to have to pipe to xargs and sed but just hitting a mental block.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.so.*'|xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' test/'{}'`

Answer (score 1):

Think I'm just going to go with something like this

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.so.*' -exec cp '{}' test/'{}' \;
for f in test/*.so.* ; do mv "$f" "${f%.*.*}" ; done`

seems to work ok from my tests

Comment: Nice. It won't matter with a smallish number of files, but, generally - if feasible - you can make `-exec` much more efficient by using `+` rather than `\;` as the terminator, which passes (typically) _all_ file paths _at once_, but, sadly, only if `{}` is the _last_ argument; on Linux, you can use `cp`'s `-t` option to work around that, however :  `-exec cp -t test/ {} +`. As an aside: While it certainly doesn't hurt, in POSIX-like shells you needn't quote `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function + script to make the job easy

```
#!/bin/bash
specialised_copy(){
version="${1##*so.}"
# extract the version part alone in the above step
cp "$1" "test/${1%%.so*}.so.${version%%.*}" 
#cut the major version part from the version and use it for copy
#note folder test should be relative to where the script is saved
}
export -f specialised_copy
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.so.*' -exec bash -c 'specialised_copy "$1"' _ {} \;
```